# Methods to move data between schemas (and database clusters) in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, migration

I am facing an enormous task: I need to move data from a very old and active schema to a new schema with different table structures. The new schema is on the development machine whereas the old schema is on the web server. Both schemas are 4th degree normalized.

What tools are available in PostgreSQL to help with this? Is there a recommended way of doing this?

(I will be updating to the current version of PostgreSQL from the older 9.2 version).

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: You need to update your title to indicate that you are actually moving between database clusters. That adds a whole another dimension to problem.

Comment: Are you going to upgrade Postgres version before doing data transfer? If so you could use [postgres_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/postgres-fdw.html) to set up foreign tables in new database that you could then pull data out of to populate the new tables. This is really going to need more information though: Size of data? Network distance of machines? How different are table structures?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver The older Active web server is on 9.2. The development schema is on the current version of PostgreSQL.  But, I'll do whatever seems easiest. Thanks.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver The machines are in the same building--I could probably put them in the same room. The data size is roughly 1GB divided between about 80 tables. Thanks.

Comment: There is a lot missing from your problem description and this is not the forum for an encyclopedic answer.  Basically you have my previous suggestion with `postgres_fdw` on the new server. Or take a `pg_dump` of the old server, restore it to the new server in the old schema and then migrate the data to the tables in the new schema.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver No good tools to compare schema's and/or tables and/or columns? Thanks.

Comment: You search on 'database schema compare' and find no end of tools. There is this [Schema diff](https://www.sql-workbench.eu/manual/compare-commands.html#command-schema-diff) which is open source. I have not used.